# Inline style for DIV allows border, but not CSS

Tags: html, css

There's obviously something fundamental I don't understand about styling so please help me out.

Let's take the following simple HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
        Hi!
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

So I have a DIV inside of a DIV and you can see a nice border around it. All is well. Now, let's remove the inline style and put it inside a CSS file.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>
<div>
    <div class="test">
        Hi!
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

No border appears now. I've tested this on both Chrome and Firefox so I don't think this is browser-specific behavior. There's certainly a good reason why there's no border in the second case but I can't seem to find it. Why is this and how do I fix it in my CSS?

Comment: Your stylesheet is probably not loading. Check the browser console.

Comment: use !important in the css file

Comment: try to give '.test' a background color. my bet is it will not work either, because your stylesheet isnt loaded properly

Comment: 1. incorrect file path. 2. older version of stylesheet in cache. 3. using `<style>` tags in your .css document.

Comment: See the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wA3PY/)

Comment: Try changing the code to add the CSS file to be like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">`. Note I added `type="text/css"` to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CSS` file mustn't be getting loaded somehow or you have an older version cached in your browser.

Your code works fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bPk2/) it is working in a jsFiddle.

Try performing a hard refresh (generally <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac) and ensuring your `CSS` file is located in the same directory as the `HTML` file you're trying to open.

Comment: Huh, that was it, Ctrl-F5 fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the css file in a sub folder?

If so, you'll need to point to it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="subfoldername/test.css" />
```